# Translating a function from Python to C++

Tags: python, c++

Im struggling with a certain function in Python, it's nothing complicated but i need to "translate" it to C++ with very limited prior knowledge.

```
def BuildCommandList(commands : list, filepath : str):

    commands.clear()

    try:
        file = open(filepath, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return False

    for line in file:
        line = line.replace('\n','')

        if len(line) != 0:      
            line = line.split()             
            commands.append(line)
    file.close()

    return True
```

Above is the function in Python, below is my current attempt at the same thing in C++

```
bool BuildCommandList(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& commandList, std::string filepath)
{
    
    std::ifstream test(filepath);
    test.open(filepath);

    if (test.is_open())
    {
        std::string line, text;
        while (std::getline(test, line))
        {
            if (!line.empty() || line.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos)
            {
                text += line + "\n";
            }

            if (len(line) != 0); //Obviusly doesn't work
            {

            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: whats wrong with your attempt? What is the code supposed to do, what does it do instead?

Comment: Can you explain what does "struggling with" mean? Which part of the shown C++ code is not working for you? What results do you expect? What results are you getting? When you used your debugger to run your C++ program, one line at a time, and show the values of all variables when the results are different, what did you see?

Comment: I don't really know if my attempt so far is necessarily wrong, it doesn't really "do" anything yet, the program itself is an assembler? it reads assembly files, and right now im stuck at trying to make this function, it opens a file and reads it, but i don't know how to do the "if len(line) != 0: ..." part in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural equivalent to Python's `len` is `std::size`, or equivalently the `size` member of `std::string`. However you might prefer the `empty` member of `std::string` for your condition.

You then need to split your string. This can be done with a [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to construct a [`std::vector<std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (overload 5) in place.

Note that `getline` doesn't include the `\n`, so you don't need to modify `line` before splitting it.

```
bool BuildCommandList(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& commandList, std::string filepath)
{
    commandList.clear();

    std::ifstream test(filepath);
    if (!test)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (std::string line; std::getline(test, line); )
    {
        if (!line.empty())
        {
            using iterator = std::istream_iterator<std::string>;
            commandList.emplace_back(iterator{std::stringstream{line}}, iterator{});
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```